# Problems loading shared library using LD_PRELOAD

Tags: spotify, alsa, ld-preload

I have a legacy system that was working on a previous system but cannot get it working.

The system:
I have a Asus Xonar 7,1 audio card. I previously had spotify for Linux running on it. What I had running before was the 7.1 card with all channels hooked up to a 8 channel amplifier.
I used .asoundrc with multiple pcm devices representing each set of speakers i.e.

```
pcm.study {
    type route
    slave {
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        channels 8
    }
    ttable {
        0.2= 1
        1.3= 1
    }
}
```

This was repeated for each room.
The original spotify for Linux did not let me select the audio device so I wrote a shared lib that intercepted the snd_pcm_open and modified the device name based on a value in a file then used

```
dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "snd_pcm_open")
```

to open the desired device. I had a separate daemon to set the value in this file.

The original spotify for linux is no longer supported, so I have tried the snap package after installing debian 12 and have managed to get the separate pcm devices playing thru the desired outputs using aplay -D study.

I have written an app that plays a wave file to the default alsa device and used the LD_PRELOAD to preload my lib and it works Ok.

For all other apps I am getting various different problems.
for spotify (snap install) and a few other apps using librespot I get

```
ld.so: object 'alsaselect.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

I have tried full paths to the lib and just the library name.
I have used LD_DEBUG and strace on the load but cannot see why it is failing.

With vlc I can load the library but when I intercept snd_pcm_open the function dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "snd_pcm_open") returns NULL

vlc can play the pcm devices Ok from it's device selection menu.

Am unsure whether to continue down this path.
Is there another way to achieve this. I have very little trouble implementing this originally, but am unsure if something in the OS has changed (I think the original would be less than debian 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok resolved this via a different path.

It appears the reason the LD_PRELOAD failed was that the new spotify app is a snap app and it appears the container system is stopping the preload. Likewise the other app I tried https://github.com/xou816/spot was distributed as a flatpak  has the same issue.

Do not really understand what is causing the load failure, as I would assume that it might load but fail to work, but I can ignore that.

Solved it by cloning the spot repo and compiling it so I can run it as a local app. My original LD_PRELOAD now loads and works as before.